# How can I join two collections spring-data-mongdb as ManyToMany (RDBMS)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this sample example from https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo/ that I'm trying to use mongodb as my backend, but I'm getting error because of the code in `JwtUserFactory.java`

```
return authorities.stream()
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName().name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Its because of the `Authority` & `User` class in `model.security` package which use the RDBMS joins, but I'm using mongodb and getting error in my code. I have the `Authority` & `User` defined for Mongodb as below. Can anyone guide me to get the working

**Authority.java**

```
@Document(collection = "authority")
public class Authority {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private AuthorityName name;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<User> users;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public AuthorityName getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(AuthorityName name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long _id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String email;

    private Boolean enabled;

    private Date lastPasswordResetDate;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<Authority> authorities;

    public Long getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public List<Authority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<Authority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public Date getLastPasswordResetDate() {
        return lastPasswordResetDate;
    }

    public void setLastPasswordResetDate(Date lastPasswordResetDate) {
        this.lastPasswordResetDate = lastPasswordResetDate;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Double> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**Exception**

Below is the exception i get

```
    org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: null
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.parkcity.security.controller.AuthenticationRestController.createAuthenticationToken(AuthenticationRestController.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.parkcity.security.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:58) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.parkcity.security.JwtUserFactory.mapToGrantedAuthorities(JwtUserFactory.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.parkcity.security.JwtUserFactory.create(JwtUserFactory.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.parkcity.security.service.JwtUserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(JwtUserDetailsServiceImpl.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 93 common frames omitted

2017-01-13 00:04:11.543 DEBUG 30067 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2017-01-13 00:04:11.544 DEBUG 30067 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@12337118
2017-01-13 00:04:11.544 DEBUG 30067 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: What error do you get ? The code you have doesn't look like is going to join to any collection.

Comment: @SagarReddy Please see the update

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically you have more then one single problem with your code. First of all the project which you are referring to is created based on JPA (that is relational database) and if you want to use the same code base with Mongo DB (document store) at least you need to rethink the data model (User and Authority). But at first lets try to make this example work and at the end I would just advise what could have changed also.

First of all if you are using the MongoDb for best experience the domain object `id` fields should have a String type, as you know mongodb stores the ids as `ObjectId` bson type which can't be converted into Long. So at first change the User.java into

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String _id;

    // bla bla bla
}
```

Same with Authority object

```
@Document(collection = "authority")
public class Authority {

    @Id
    private String _id;

    // TODO remove this right now !!! :)
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<User> users;

    // bla bla bla
}
```

And UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

After this two changes you will need to refactor the references as well.

You have a reference from Authorities to Users ? !!! Whats that ? :) That is something from JPA, with MongoDb this reference makes no sense. Just remove it !!

The next thing with the project is that it relies on a fact that the datastore has some predefined data see the `import.sql`, so same for MongoDb you need to import a data into mongodb to be able to run the project. I have converted the import.sql into MongoShell format so you can use it.

Insert this into `authority` collection:

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("587cb19d1db2732183afb0a9"), 
   "_class" : "org.parkcity.model.security.Authority", 
   "name" : "ROLE_ADMIN"
}
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("587cb19d1db2732183afb0aa"), 
   "_class" : "org.parkcity.model.security.Authority", 
   "name" : "ROLE_USER"
}
```

Insert this into `user` collection:

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("587cb19d1db2732183afb0ab"), 
   "_class" : "org.parkcity.model.security.User", 
   "username" : "admin", 
   "password" : "$2a$08$lDnHPz7eUkSi6ao14Twuau08mzhWrL4kyZGGU5xfiGALO/Vxd5DOi", 
   "firstname" : "admin", 
   "lastname" : "admin", 
   "email" : "admin@admin.com", 
   "enabled" : true, 
   "lastPasswordResetDate" : ISODate("2017-01-16T11:42:21.537+0000"), 
   "authorities" : [
       DBRef("authority", ObjectId("587cb19d1db2732183afb0a9")), 
       DBRef("authority", ObjectId("587cb19d1db2732183afb0aa"))
   ]
 }
 { 
   "_id" : ObjectId("587cb1a11db2732183afb0ac"), 
   "_class" : "org.parkcity.model.security.User", 
   "username" : "user", 
   "password" :    "$2a$08$UkVvwpULis18S19S5pZFn.YHPZt3oaqHZnDwqbCW9pft6uFtkXKDC", 
   "firstname" : "user", 
   "lastname" : "user", 
   "email" : "user@user.com", 
   "enabled" : true, 
   "lastPasswordResetDate" : ISODate("2017-01-16T11:42:21.620+0000"), 
   "authorities" : [
       DBRef("authority", ObjectId("587cb19d1db2732183afb0aa"))
   ]
}
```

As you can see I have adjusted the packages from "org.zerhusen" into "org.parkcity".

Thats it, now you can start the project and have some tests. As you can see I haven't added disabled user (so you can do that by your own).

And just for your considerations for this particular case using `@DBRefs` is pure evil :) You are on MogoDb so store the authorities in same collection and object as the users, that way it will be much faster.

**Also created a fully functional fork (based on MongoDB) which is available here** https://github.com/babltiga/jwt-spring-security-demo

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It works like a charm. I'm planning to convert this code to Microservice architecture. Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how the current project can be used for microservices

Comment: I would say you need to a micro service for authentication, that is a single service which will just take username/password pairs and return JWT tokens. For that particular case, you don;t even need Spring Security. And for all other micro services you will need Spring Security which will ensure that JWT tokens are valid and that user is authorized to access the service. Something like this .... :)

Answer (score 3):

Mongodb being document-based storage requires a different modelling mindset than you're accustomed to in SQL.

In the above case, since Authority is such a tiny object, I'd just include a

```
List<String> authorities
```

in the User. Then you have a single collection without all the cruft that is associated with having to keep referential integrity and also boosts performance.

Downside is that when changing Authorities, namely, upon rename or removal, you'll need to update all User documents, but judging your data model, that won't happen too often.